# How to make font face URL in SCSS work with a different Flask application root

Tags: css, url, flask, font-face, static-files

I have a website that uses Flask, and I use Flask-Assets with the `libsass` filter. Here is some of my SCSS code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: AnakAnak;
    src: url("/static/anakanak.ttf");
}
```

This usually works fine. However, when I set the `APPLICATION_ROOT` config value of my Flask app to `/otherpath`, the font file is now at `/otherpath/static/anakanak.ttf`, but the CSS still points to `/static/anakanak.ttf`. How can I fix this? Is there some way I can insert something like this into the CSS?

```css
src: url(url_for('static', filename='anakanak.ttf');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out a solution. Since the outputted CSS file is also going to be a static file (`/static/gen/XXXXXXXX.css`), just use a relative URL in the CSS file:

```css
src: url("../anakanak.ttf");
```

Comment: BTW. I figured out this solution just before I was about to submit this question. But I posted it anyway and wrote this answer to help people with the same problem.